# What is the definition of infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definition

What is the definition of series?
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i = 1+2+3+4\,+..$$
Would you call the left hand side "series"? Because the right hand side is the sum of the series and i don't understand why people seem to say series = sum of the series. Seems like a simplification.

I believe I was taught that infinite series is a sequence of growing partial sums of another sequence. For example:
$$series\;example = (1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4,...) = (1,3,6,10,15,21,...)$$
Are series some sort of sequences or are they inifnite sums?

Comment: A series is a limit of partial sums, so $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n i.$$ In this case the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It is referred to as a "divergent series" since the limit of the partial sums does not converge to a number.  _Some_ divergent series can be treated in specific ways to be given a value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series .  In regard to your last questions, a sequence is a "list" of terms with a series being their sum (where definable).  There are finite series; the one you have is an example of an infinite series.

Comment: I would say a series is more like a sum of the *sequence* rather than a sum of the series.

Comment: +1 Good question. I usually use "sum of the series" to mean the value that the series takes if the series converges. But saying "sum of the series" is probably just poor wording on my part. However, it is clear what is *meant* by "sum of the series", so whilst this may be bad English, the meaning behind it (which is what I care about) is clear and unambiguous, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series in the form
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i$
admits *two* different interpretations.

- It can be seen as *sequence*  of partial sums
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i:= \left(1,3,6,\ldots\right) =\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)_{n\geq 1}
  \end{align*}
- and it can be seen as *limit* of the sequence of partial sums
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n i
  \end{align*}

*Note:* You can find this line of argumentation  e.g. in *[Theory and Application of Infinite Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486661652)* by K. Knopp.

Answer (score 1):

We denote

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i = 1+2+3+4\,+\dots+n$$

as a sum or [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) and by definition

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n i$$

as a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)), which can be convergent to a finite value or not, while

$$(1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4,\dots)$$

is the [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) of the partial sums.

Comment: So what is the sum of the series? Is the sum of the series the series itself? Do these two concepts mean the exact same thing?

Comment: @Glue A series is the limit of a sum and therefore, when the series converges, it assumes a value (not always converges). The sum/summation always has a finite value (it is not a limit, it is a summation of a finite number of terms).

Comment: @user "A series is the limit of a sum". Isn't it more proper to say, "a series is the limit of a sequence of partial sums". Or are both statements correct?

Comment: @AdamRubinson The definitions sound equivalent to me! But I'm not native english speaker, therefore I'm glad to receive suggestions and corrections on that. Thanks